# java long values rounded off in json response

Tags: java, json

While getting a JSON response from my restful service implemented in JAVA, I am observing that the long data type values  ending with 01 are rounded off to 00.
For example:

the long values,

`12345123459876501 is returned as 12345123459876500 (last digit rounded to 0)`

`12345123459876502 is returned as 12345123459876502`

`12345123451234501 is returned as 12345123451234500 (last digit rounded to 0)`

`12345123451234502 is returned as 12345123451234502`

Could anybody help me understand why only the values ending with 01 are getting rounded to 00?

Comment: Nope, not without you showing how the service is implemented or how you are parsing the JSON.

Comment: i am using POSTMAN to check my JSON response from my service.

Comment: regarding the implementation, my response is sent via the javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder object as below
<br/>
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getHttpStatus());
<br/>
  responseBuilder.entity(entity);
<br/>
  return responseBuilder.build(); 
<br/>
The entity is an object which has the long value as one of the element

Comment: maybe a bit of code help.

Comment: regarding the implementation, my response is sent via the javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder object as below

<code>
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getHttpStatus());

  responseBuilder.entity(entity);

  return responseBuilder.build(); 
</code>
The entity is an object which has the long value as one of the element

Comment: Since this is the first time I am trying to use this forum, I am not aware of how to format my code snippet. hence i have copy pasted as above

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t - the precision is lost on the client-side javascript, the java code receives the result of converting the floating-point number to integer, which looks like rounding of the lowest digits.

Comment: @BalajiBabu [SO comment formatting help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24793/213583)

Comment: Note that you don't get `long` (or `double`) values from a JSON parser, you get `Long` or `Double` or one of the `Big...` classes.  You can get a valid type and then bungle it by using the wrong `xxxValue` method to access it, among other possibilities.

Comment: Copy/paste a bit of the JSON source containing the values in question.

Answer (score 7):

JSON as defined at [json.org](http://json.org/) has just a single numeric type called "number". So many JSON parsers for Java will map that to `double` type regardless of whether it is used for integer, long, of floating-point numbers. However, a `double` can only hold 15-16 significant digits while a `long` can store more. So if you have a `long` value with more digits than that, precision is lost when the JSON parser converts between `long` and `double`, which changes your `01` suffix to `00`. If you want to be sure all digits are preserved, you must change your field type to `String` and handle parsing to `long` by yourself.

Comment: But note that good JSON parsers will avoid any loss of precision by choosing an appropriate "Big" data type if need be.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe some do, but at least Jackson collapses all numeric types to `double` internally.

Comment: Um, no, Jackson does not convert numeric types to `double` internally. I don't know where the idea came from, but it is completely false. With data-mapping, resulting number is determined by POJO structure, but intermediate representation fully preserves accuracy using (if need be) `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`